Scale instances based on mesh edge length
I am trying to scale cylinders (instances) to make them fit to each edge they are spawned on. Unfortunately, hours of attempts amount to nothing.
Here's the initial setup.

If I use "Edge Vertices -> Distance (Vector Math)" nodes to capture edge length data, it spits out a field data into a spreadsheet that accurately represents each edge length.

However, once it plugs into a "Scale", it returns 0, 0, 0, even if using Separate/Combine XYZ nodes. I have no idea why.

Interestingly, if I connect Separate XYZ -> Combine XYZ nodes, the spreadsheet will show the same numbers divided by 3.

Any help is much appreciated as I am completely lost on how to achieve the desired effect.

The problem here is the Scale you get is based on the current geometry used in the Instance on Points node - and the current geometry is just points generated by the Mesh to Points node, so there is no more Distance between two endpoints of an edge, that is why the value is 0.
What you have to do is use a Capture Attribute node before the Mesh to Points node, plug the Distance in there and the output in the Combine XYZ node:

By the way, I cannot see the settings of your cylinder, but if you have left the Depth value at the default 2 m, then this scaling method will make the cylinders twice the width of the edges. If they should be the same width, set Depth to 1 m.
